# PHP Foreach loop to display the description only of That post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, loops, foreach

I use wordpress and I want to achieve that on every page I would see different title and description from my custom field:

> 1 page (the id is 1) tile, description
>
> 2 page (the id is 2) title, description
>
> etc..

I've tried this piece of code with different variations (now it is only showing the id), but all i achieved is that it would just put all of the titles and descriptions on every page.

```
$titles = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_aioseop_title' OR meta_key='_aioseop_description'" );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $titles[] = $row['meta_value'];
    $ids[] = $row['post_id'];
}
?>
<?php 
if ($post_id = the_id()) 
{
    foreach ($titles as $meta_key=>$meta_value)
    {
        print $post_id;
        print '<div class="white">' . $meta_value . '</div>';
        print '<div class="green">' . $meta_value . '</div>';
    };
}
?>
```

Any idea or link to tutorial or a hint would be highly helpful.

Comment: where does $post_id come from? not a wp expert, but I guess you should stick that ID into your SQL somewhere. Right now your SQL retrieves too many articles

Comment: You see, post_id is the row in the database, which comes along with row meta_key and meta_value, the last one i'm trying to display. So in order to do so, i need to match post_id with the_id of the page i am currently in, to display only those meta_values, that come along with the post_id.

Patrick de Vries method worked, it shows me the stuff i need, but i'm still waiting for an answer to display the $meta_data['aioseop_title']; cause I somehow can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first only fetch the title and description of that specific post. That can be done by making sure the field `post_id` equals `get_the_ID()`:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_key='_aioseop_title' OR meta_key='_aioseop_description') AND `post_id` = '".get_the_ID()."';");
```

Then you can read the results into variables;

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $meta_data[$row["meta_key"]] = $row["meta_value"];
}
```

Now `$meta_data["_aioseop_title"]` should contain the title, and `$meta_data["_aioseop_description"]` should contain the description.

Comment: ok, makes ton of sense. so do i still write the foreach loop, or i just can use the $meta_data["_aioseop_title"] and $meta_data["_aioseop_description"] as variables and stick them in? 

<div class="white"><?php $meta_data["_aioseop_title"]; ?></div>

Comment: You still need the loop as this read all results from the query you've sent to the database. Without the loop, there would be no `$meta_data["_aioseop_title"]` or `$meta_data["_aioseop_description"]`.

Edit: I also had an error inside the while statement which I've edited now.

Comment: yes, when you edited your while statement i finally got a result in var_dump($meta_data) and it's exactly what we need - title and description of THAT page. i will try to write a proper loop now

Answer (score 0):

Your query gets all post metadata - restrict it to post_id = the_id()

Comment: can u please write all of the code? i'm kinda new in this thing

Answer (score 0):

Ok with Patrickdev's help I managed to do it :) Though somehow, when i wrote foreach loop all it did is displayed the title and description twice (for each element in meta_data array), so when i deleted foreach and just used the elements from that array, it started working as it should :)

Here's the code if anyone needs it:

```
<?php           

                                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_key='_aioseop_title' OR meta_key='_aioseop_description') AND `post_id` = '".get_the_ID()."' ORDER BY meta_id DESC;");

                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                                        {
                                            $meta_data[$row["meta_key"]] = $row["meta_value"];
                                        }
                                            print '<div class="white">' . $meta_data["_aioseop_title"] . '</div>';
                                            print '<div class="green">' . $meta_data["_aioseop_description"] . '</div>';
                                ?>
```

Thanks again, Patrickdev.